# use CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE with wordpress wp_remote_post

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on api connect to our server IP to get result to my wordpress but when i make a call using wp_remote_post the response back with error access denied because of the wp_remote_post use IPv6 and api serveice connect with our IPv4.

So my question is how to use CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE to force wp_remote_post call to use IPv4 not IPv6.

I tried to add this filter before wp_remote_post call

`add_filter('http_request_args', function ($args) { // Check if cURL options are already set if (!isset($args['curl'])) { // If not set, initialize the array $args['curl'] = array(); } // Set CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE to CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 $args['curl'][CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE] = CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4; return $args; });`

but i got same response Access denied.